# How can I use an Nvidia GPU with an open-source embedded board?

Tags: embedded, pcie, gpu

Is it possible by any means or method, to use an Nvidia GPU with an (probably open-source) embedded board? If yes, how do I go about achieving that? I have a few ideas but I'm just a beginner, hence not sure about the feasibility:

1. Replace the on-board GPU with Nvidia GPU (since the board schematics are available, this should be somehow possible right?)
2. Connect the GPU externally on a board with an exposed PCIe interface. (I'm pretty sure I don't understand this, but if its possible to hook up an Nvidia GPU to a laptop/PC and start gaming, shouldn't this be feasible? )

*Why Nvidia GPU?*
I need to run a CUDA-based application for my project. For details on my problem: [Embedded board (preferably < $150) with external gpu support?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/317767/embedded-board-preferably-150-with-external-gpu-support)

Comment: This is not a beginner project.

Comment: The question reveals a distinct lack of required knowlege. You will be a lot better off using a desktop PC with a nomal Nvidia graphics card. Currently (mid 2017) the best bang-for-buck are used GTX 760 cards at around $50.

Comment: I'm a professional EE and at a guess this would take me weeks of full time effort to get working

Comment: [Dunning Kruger](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%25E2%2580%2593Kruger_effect&ved=0ahUKEwi5zcq7n53VAhWJIJoKHTRHDs8QFggdMAA&usg=AFQjCNHdFxS5Ah_HTg_qxfHGGMUYQzRviA) hard at work here. Your 2nd option (which you seem to think is more difficult) is far, far more achievable.

Comment: Almost any mini-ITX PC mainboard will cost under $150, https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157726 The only way to add "NVIDIA GPU" is to get a PCIe videocard.

Comment: What's wrong with the Nvidia motherboard you linked to in your other question? That has a GPU on board. https://www.amazon.com/NVIDIA-Jetson-TK1-Development-Kit/dp/B00L7AWOEC/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1500743310&sr=1-1&keywords=NVIDIA+Jetson+TK1+Development+Kit

Comment: There are boards that provides PCIE 1X or even 4X slots, so hardware is not the show stopper. However the GPU driver has traditionally been very closed and you might have difficulty get driver to run on a non-X86 cpu.

Comment: But if you just want cuda, why not use just use Tegra? Or re-writing cuda in opencl would be much easier than getting nvidia driver to work with ARM.

Comment: @brhans, Sorry for asking such a silly question. I'm a CS major, and pretty much a duck at this. Guess I'll have to take on-board an EE person.

Comment: @user3528438 "re-writing cuda in opencl would be much easier than getting nvidia driver to work with ARM" Thanks, I'll research more into that. Any pointers (if possible) could be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

You need the following components:

1. An nVidia GPU, which has a PCIe interface generally
2. The necessary support components for power supply and heat management
3. Drivers that know how to send commands to the GPU and retrieve results
4. A compiler that translates CUDA to the internal binary format

The latter two are available as closed source programs for Windows and Linux running on Intel/AMD processors.

The GPUs are sold standalone only to companies that buy several thousand units, as interfacing the IC is difficult and close to undoable without support from nVidia, so they won't bother for a few units only.

If it really has to be CUDA, your best bet is to take a standard graphics card and interface it through PCIe.

If OpenCL is fine, then I'd go with an FPGA based solution, e.g. from Xilinx or Altera -- interfacing FPGAs is a bit better documented as there are several people using low- to midrange FPGAs and writing articles about it. Building a stable and spec-compliant power supply for a high-end FPGA is still nontrivial, but at least the documentation is available, and ICs are sold separately.

Comment: Yes, and to develop any add-on card based on GPU or FPGA, the OP will need a CAD software capable of 6-8-12 layers of PCB, and find a design house that is capable to mount 1000's pin BGA chips (maybe several $K to run)...etc etc.

Comment: @AliChen, but these are minor issues compared to the others :)

Comment: Thank you for so much info. 
"your best bet is to take a standard graphics card and interface it through PCIe." If I consider the mini-ITX board in @AliChen 's comment on the original post, and connect an nvidia gpu graphics card through pcie, is that the right way to go? Or am I missing something that I should know?

Comment: "If OpenCL is fine, then I'd go with an FPGA based solution" Like I said in the link mentioned (the other question), I have NI myRIO but never utilised its FPGA, I'll look more into whether the CUDA-based library can be tweaked to work with OpenCL, following @user3528438 's advice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the NVidia CUDA developer network.
To choose an embedded platform readily capable of supporting CUDA pre-compiled transfers start [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). It's very much easier to choose a Linux solution IMO.
The download package is Open-Source so you can alter it to suit your requirements.

You can pre-ccompile your CUDA source anywhere you want, MAC/PC/Linux desktops.
Since I use Visual Studio I'll add that you need to be aware of some restrictions  and gotchas if you want to use the latest compiler....see [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements).
Be aware when using the older GPU's you may have to cross compile back to operate on 32bit Windows versions.

You can easily get an NVidia GPU to work over an x1 PCie line (most of you embedded CPU choices will only be x1), but you may end up writing your own communications software. Choose a GPU that works in a desktop and has up to date drivers, then you can do the vast majority of your debug on the desktop.

I'd assume you then need to choose a lower power GPU that works well on PCie x1 (up to date drivers), there are lots available very cheaply, such as the GeForce-730 (GDDR5) which is less than $100 now and still readily available. This has 98 cores and is only 25 W, stunning performance for such a small GPU. (by comparison I run a 9800 GX2 in my desktop but it consumes 200 W)
You can see all the GPU cards [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus). Anything that plugs into PCie x1 will work over x1 .....I have no idea how many cores or how much power supply you want to carry.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have already got my project running well on a laptop with GeForce 820M , I needed hardware advice on shifting to embedded platform. 
"you may have to cross compile back to operate on 32bit Windows versions." Thanks. Will it be a problem if I use a graphics card (something like this: http://www.amazon.in/Gigabyte-Nvidia-GT730-Express-Graphics/dp/B00TB8XQNA/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1500767186&sr=8-4&keywords=geforce+730 ) with 32-bit Linux? Note: It only says 'Windows' in the supported operating systems.